# how to configure the hotkey of notepad++ for python?

Tags: python, notepad++

hi I am using notepad++ for python.
I want a hotkey that will run my python script at the path of the script instead of the path of notepad++.
Besides, at the end of process, i want it to show "press any key to continue".

I've tried:

1. cmd /k  "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
2. python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

But none of them meets my expectations.
For example:

```
f = open('hello.txt', 'w')
f.close()
```

This will create 'hello.txt' in the directory of notepad++, but I want to create it at the same path of this script.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good find - Notepad++ seems to always set the current working directory to it's own executable directory when scripts are run.

One workaround is to use this: [Notepad++ Python Plug-in](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/).  This is a plug-in for Notepad++ and adds options to run your scripts in Python from the Plugins menu in Notepad++ (instead of using the Run menu).  This should fix your current working directory problem.